# How can test a variable if it is an integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As the title might specify, I want to ask how can I test a variable if it is an integer. I have seen other topics and they don't seem to have code that works or that I know how to use.

```
print("Enter the weight of the bag in grams.")

weight = float(input()) # float was used as it might be a decimal sometimes

amtcoin = weight / 3.56
```

How do I test if amtcoin is a integer? As the variable suggests, it is the amount of coins and you cannot have a fraction of a coin. 
Thanks.

Comment: In this case `isinstance(amtcoin, int)` would be sufficient, but it's hard to see what you're up to and how you could ever get an int from that

Comment: `isinstance(amtcoin, int)` will always be false. because `weight / 3.56` returns float everytime, as division is done by floating point value.

Comment: Right let me clear thing up. The code is designed to test how many coins are in a bag. WEIGHT is the weight of the bag. So if the weight is 35.6 and the weight of the tested coin is 3.56, that means that there are 10 coins so AMTCOIN will be an integer. That's what I want to test. I want to ENSURE that the AMTCOIN IS an integer. It HAS to be an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`amtcoin` variable is instance of class you declare it. Declare it as float and if you want to know if it's a fraction or not check `amtcoin % 1 == 0`

Answer (score 8):

You can convert to float as you did and then check with `is_integer` method:

```
float(weight).is_integer()
```

Comment: So if the value is an integer it will do the code underneath or will it do the code if it is a float?

Comment: Yes, this would do:
if float(weight).is_integer():
   # if integer
else:
   # if float

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if int(amtcoin) == amtcoin:
    do_something()
```

If it is `int`, this condition will be met.